# does async.map guarantee results are passed in order?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async.js

If I have a series of calls over an `async.map`, is the result guaranteed to be in order? Or is the result simply the order that the requests finish? e.g.

```
var requestList = [
    { method: 'GET', url: '/something1' },
    { method: 'GET', url: '/something2' },
    { method: 'GET', url: '/something3' }];

// async map the requests together, and handle the result in
// the callback.
async.map(requestList, function(obj, callback) {
    request(obj, function(error, response, body) {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var body = JSON.parse(body);
            callback(null, body);
        } else {
            callback(error || response.statusCode);
        }
    });
}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('Error!');
    } else {
        // is result guarenteed to be in the order: [/something1, /something2, /something3] ?
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, order is gaurenteed for iterators and arrays. The order for object keys is attempted to be maintained

Answer (score 0):

If it's passed an array, I presume it'll be always in order.
And according to the official doc
'If map is passed an Object, the results will be an Array. The results will roughly be in the order of the original Objects' keys (but this can vary across JavaScript engines)'.
The doc talks nothing about the array so it's safe to assume the order will be preserved.